# How do I draw a mysql polygon circle, and not a square?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, polygon, geometry

The function below creates a polygon square out of 4 points and I assume the last 5th point closed the squar, I need it to have at least 24 points and to make up a circle. Any ideas?

```
function getRadius($point="POINT(-29.8368 30.9096)", $radius=2)
{
    $km = 0.009;
    $center = "GeomFromText('$point')";
        $radius = $radius*$km;
        $bbox = "CONCAT('POLYGON((',
                X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, ',',
                X($center) + $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, ',',
                X($center) + $radius, ' ', Y($center) + $radius, ',',
                X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) + $radius, ',',
                X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, '
        ))')";

    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT id, AsText(latLng) AS latLng, (SQRT(POW( ABS( X(latLng) - X({$center})), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(latLng) - Y({$center})), 2 )))/0.009 AS distance
        FROM crime_listing
        WHERE Intersects( latLng, GeomFromText($bbox) )
        AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(latLng) - X({$center})), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(latLng) - Y({$center})), 2 )) < $radius
        ORDER BY distance
                ");

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
                return($query->result());
        }else{
                return false;
        }
}
```

Below the the js version and this works perfect

```
var findCirclePolygons = function(point, r)
{   
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;
    this.circleLatLngs = new Array();
    numPoints = 24;
    var circleLat = r * 0.009;  // Convert degrees into km
    var circleLng = circleLat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r);
    for (var i = 0; i < numPoints + 1; i++) {
        var theta = Math.PI * (i / (numPoints / 2));
        var vertexLat = point.lat() + (circleLat * Math.sin(theta));
        var vertexLng = parseFloat(point.lng()) + parseFloat(( circleLng * Math.cos(theta)));
        var vertextLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(vertexLat, vertexLng);
        this.circleLatLngs.push(vertextLatLng);
    }

    // Set options
    var options = {
        paths: circleLatLngs,
        strokeColor: "#0055ff",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#0055ff",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
        };

    // Return
    return options;
};
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Please add the homework tag if it is.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find all points within a circle centered at (X, Y). Would't you be better off working out the distance of each point from (X, Y), and checking that distance against your desired "radius"?

Comment: ... that could work too.

Comment: The first snippet makes a rectangle, not a square, because it fails to condition longitude by the cosine of the latitude.  The second appears to account for latitude correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a loop (in pseudo code):

```
for(i=0; i <= 360; i += 360/24)
{
    $extra_point = "POINT(". $radius*cos(i)." ". $radius*sin(i) . ")"
}
```

**EDIT**

- However, if you just want a bounding box, then using a square is the right way to do it. No need to have a circle looking bounding box. You filter out later with the sorting.
- To measure the distance, no need to use ABS. Squaring does it for you (as an extra, compare to the radius squared instead of computing the square root if you are extreamly picky about performances
- Don't forget to add the spatial index or the performances will be crap

**2nd EDIT**
In somewhat less pseudo-code ;) (It's been ages I didn't work with php).

```
$lon = 42;
$lat = 2;
$radius = 0.01;
$bbox = "POLYGON((";
for(i=0; i <= 360; i += 360/24)
{
    $bbox .= $radius*cos(deg2rad(i)) + $lon." ". $radius*sin(deg2rad(i)) + $lat;
    if(i < 360)"
        $bbox .= ", "
}
$bbox .= "))"
```

About the distance thing, you have pow(abs(x),2) == pow(x, 2) for any x. So you can just write (for simplicity):

```
SQRT(POW( X(latLng) - X({$center}), 2) + POW(Y(latLng) - Y({$center}), 2 )) < $radius
```

Or even to spare the computation of the square root (in this case it won't change absolutely anything and early optimization is a bad thing, so do as you whish)

```
POW( X(latLng) - X({$center}), 2) + POW(Y(latLng) - Y({$center}), 2 ) < POW($radius, 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, except I need the "$bbox" to be the "circle". But I do see what you mean by the bounding box and filtering out the extra points, I'm going to give it a try. thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Im going to give this another try.